# Btn Bootstrap 3.3.7 don't work Show/Hide

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button

I've got problem with button. I can open content, but when I click again, nothing change while it  should close...

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Bio-chemia</title>
</head>

.....

<div id="Biophura" class="container text-center">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo89">BIOPHURA</button>
  <div id="demo89" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Have missed the closing `div` tag.

```
<div id="Biophura" class="container text-center">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo89">BIOPHURA</button>
  <div id="demo89" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Biophura" class="container text-center">
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo89">BIOPHURA</button>
  <div id="demo89" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

> that is work 100%

**your problem is in script link**